# Send an email once an hour even though page refreshes every minute

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

Using VB.net and VS 2015 to create an asp.net site.

I have a web page that refreshes automatically every minute and it shows the status of several items.  I want to be able to send an email from the page every 60 minutes if an error is found.  I would prefer to use only the code within the site but I have access to sql server 2012 to create a DB if needed.

I thought the best way to do this is if there was an error on the page call a subroutine to send the email.  As it stands this would happen every minute which would get annoying.  I thought the best way to do this would be with a session variable but I cannot work out how to send the email only once every 60 mins and then stop when the error is no longer present and reset the time back to 0.

The code below shows what I have so far.  This is wrapped by a case statement checking for the error.

```
'checks to see if email needs to be sent
Select Case Session("sendEmail")
    Case Nothing, 60, 120, 180
        'send email
    Case Else
        'do nothing
End Select

Session("sendEmail") = Session("sendEmail") + 1
```

This should work as after the page has refreshed 60 times the session variable will match the case statement but I need it to send emails until someone has resolved the error and I dont want to hardcode a list of numbers incrementing by 60 each time in the case statement.

Comment: Store the errors in a session variable using a list<string>  every minute.In Page_Load call a method that checks whether the hour mark has reached,something like DateTime.Now.Hour == 1 || DateTime.Now.Hour == 2 || DateTime.Now.Hour == 3 and so on... If yes then read the errors and send an email.Once the error is fixed remove the item from the list<string> and reassign it to the session.

Answer (score 0):

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx for info on case statments.

see [working with SELECT CASE and MOD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586017/working-with-select-case-and-mod) for case statements with using mod before hand.

```
Dim number As Integer
number = 180
Dim remainder As Integer
remainder = number Mod 60
'checks to see if email needs to be sent
Select Case remainder
    Case 0
        Console.WriteLine("divisible by 60")
    Case Else
        Console.WriteLine("not divisible by 60")
End Select
```

Comment: @Silentbob sorry misread your question initially I have just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Mod` operator to divide by 60 minutes and get the remainder, so you don't need to check for 60, 120, 180 etc.

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx) on Mod

```
Dim minutes as Integer 

If Not Session("sendEmail") Is Nothing Then
    minutes = TryCast(Session("sendEmail"), Integer)
Else
    minutes = 0
End If

'checks to see if email needs to be sent
If (minutes Mod 60) > 1
   'send email
   minutes = 0 ' reset counter
Else
   minutes = minutes + 1
End If

Session("sendEmail") = minutes
```